# PostgreSQL array formatting in functions

Tags: arrays, postgresql, jsonb

I need to change the array format from `[1,2]` to `{1,2}`.

I wrote a function for that:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION core.format_array(
    parray integer[])
    RETURNS integer[]
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'

    COST 100
    VOLATILE 
AS $BODY$
DECLARE
    arrayValue    integer[];        
-- select core.format_array(Array [1,2]);
BEGIN

    begin
      select parray into arrayValue;
    end;
    RETURN arrayValue;
END
$BODY$;
```

And I want to use this function in another functions like this:

```
{"test":[1,2]}//passing the array

test = params ->> 'test';
select core.format_array(ARRAY test::int[]) into test;
```

I can't even save the function it shows this error

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "test"

LINE 22:  select core.format_array(ARRAY test::int[]) into test;
```

Since I can't use `Array` in front of the variable, I removed it:

```
select core.format_array(test::int[]) into test;
```

This time the function saved successfully, but querying for the output it shows an exception:

```
INFO:  Error Name:malformed array literal: "[1,2]"
INFO:  Error State:22P02
```

So what I am doing wrong?

**EDIT**
with the help of @Laurenz Albe I have changed my function a little bit

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION core.format_array(
    parray text)
    RETURNS integer[]
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'

    COST 100
    VOLATILE 
AS $BODY$
DECLARE
    arrayValue    integer[];        
-- select core.format_array('[1,2]');
BEGIN

    begin
    SELECT array_agg(x)::int[] into arrayValue
FROM jsonb_array_elements_text(parray::jsonb) AS x(x);
      --select parray into arrayValue;
    end;
    RETURN arrayValue;
END
$BODY$;
```

And I passed the value as `{"test":"[1,2]"}`

```
select core.format_array( params ->> 'test') into test;
```

Now it is working

Comment: I think you've misunderstood somewhat about arrays here. It's not that the "format" of any array is `[1,2]` . It is a text representation of a json array and `{1,2}` represents a normal postgres array. They are not referred to as different "format" s  of any array as you've mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some misconceptions:

- `jsonb` arrays are different from PostgreSQL array types like `integer[]`
- while the text representation of a `jsonb` array is `[1,2]`, an `integer[]` is represented as `{1,2}`

This explains your problems.

As a solution, consider using something like

```
SELECT array_agg(x)::text INTO textvar
FROM jsonb_array_elements_text(params->'test') AS x(x);
```

Comment: my data type is not jsonb it is integer[]

Comment: Then how can you use the `->>` operator?

Comment: Ok then which operator I need to use?